# TS Redux extends type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, rtk-query

I am using Redux with React and Typescript.

I followed official Redux docs "Usage with TypeScript" section https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript.

```
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

It's works ok until I started using actions from my extrenal lib.

In React component I type dispatch function like follow:

```
const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch()
...
dispatch(initForm("my_form", { name: "John"} ))
```

I would like type values which I pass to the `initForm` action.

In future I would like solve this typing in my extrenal library, propably via declaration files, but for now, I need solve at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sufficient short-term solution.

First I created helper interface.

```
export type initFormDispatchI<form, inputsI> = (form: form, inputs: inputsI) => any
```

And then I use type assertion within `initForm` function.

```
export interface formInputsI {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

dispatch((initForm as initFormDispatchI<"user_form", formInputsI>)(
    "user_form",
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 18,
        no_exist_propt: "" // throw Error 
    }
))
```